# Is there a reason I should prefix my CSS properties while also using autoprefixers?

Tags: sass, less, prefix, autoprefixer

I have been working on projects with legacy code for a while now. Even though those projects use autoprefixers for [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer) or [Grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-autoprefixer), I still find prefixed properties in the SCSS and LESS files I'm hesitant to clean out like these :

```
-webkit-transition: width 0.1s ease-out;
-moz-transition: width 0.1s ease-out;
-ms-transition: width 0.1s ease-out;
-o-transition: width 0.1s ease-out;
transition: width 0.1s ease-out;
```

I asked the question to previous devs already and 95% of the time the answer is "I don't know, it was like that before, better not touch it"

Is there a reason CSS properties should be prefixed while using autoprefixers or are there exceptions I'm not aware of ?

Comment: Those are used for browser support. If you want to support as much browsers as possible do not delete them. A few usefull articles [mozzila.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) [csstricks](https://css-tricks.com/is-vendor-prefixing-dead/)

Comment: @dudule But isn't it the point of autoprefixers to do this ?

Comment: Yes. I don't think you should bother with anything more that autoprefixer.